# Use UNION in Codeigniter and get error?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, union

I want select data with `UNION` as follow:

```
$find = 'hello';
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE '%$find%' UNION SELECT * FROM tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE '%$find%''); // Line number 46
```

But I encounter this error:

```
> A PHP Error was encountered<br> Severity: Warning<br> Message:
> Division by zero<br> Filename: foreign.php<br> Line Number: 46<br>
> 
> A Database Error Occurred<br> The query you submitted is not
> valid.<br> Filename:
> D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php<br> Line
> Number: 257<br>
```

How can I fix it?

**Update:**

Error:

```
> A Database Error Occurred<br> Error Number: 1222<br> The used SELECT
> statements have a different number of columns<br> SELECT * FROM
> tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE "%hello%" UNION SELECT * FROM
> tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE "%hello%"<br> Filename:
> D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php<br> Line Number: 330<br>
```

Comment: Please provide the structure of the 2 tables used. If you're going to union them the column names must match (or you need to match them by assigning them labels that match).

Answer (score 2):

You're throwing single quotes in the string without escaping them. That could be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Table `tour_foreign_residence` and `tour_foreign` have a different number of columns. Remove `*` after each select to set the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE '%$find%' UNION SELECT * FROM tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE '%$find%'');
```

to

```
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tour_foreign_residence WHERE name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" UNION SELECT * FROM tour_foreign WHERE name LIKE "%' . $find . '%"');
```

Comment: I use of your code but have new error, please see update in my post and tell me.

Comment: The columns of the 2 tables don't match. Please provide the output for `DESCRIBE tour_foreign_residence;` and `DESCRIBE tour_foreign;` so I can see what columns the tables have.